# Does the meaning of this sentence change with commas?

Tags: punctuation, commas

What is the difference of meaning between these two sentences?

> 1. Mary who is my wife has gone to Singapore.
> 2. Mary, who is my wife, has gone to Singapore.

Comment: [*A **restrictive** modifying clause (or **essential** clause) is an adjective clause that is essential to the meaning of a sentence because it limits the thing it refers to. The meaning of the sentence would change if the clause were deleted. Because **restrictive clauses** are essential, they **are not set off by commas**.*](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/) In your example we can discount the possibility that you're distinguishing ***your wife*** from other people called Mary, so it's a ***non-restrictive clause***, which requires commas (or pause in speech).

Comment: In other words, there isn't a difference in _meaning_, but 1 is grammatically incorrect and 2 is grammatically correct.

Comment: There is a girl, a namesake of my wife, who hasn't gone anywhere. If so, is 1 grammatically correct?

Comment: @theinlwin I'm not sure I can explain why very well, but "who is my wife" wouldn't be used like that as a restrictive clause. If it's unclear who "Mary" is, the sentence would be rephrased to _"My wife Mary has gone to Singapore."_ or perhaps in speech _"Mary, that's my wife, not my boss, has gone to Singapore."_

Answer (score 1):

@FumbleFingers answered in a comment:

> [*A **restrictive** modifying clause (or **essential** clause) is an adjective clause that is essential to the meaning of a sentence because it limits the thing it refers to. The meaning of the sentence would change if the clause were deleted. Because **restrictive clauses** are essential, they **are not set off by commas**.*](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/) In your example we can discount the possibility that you're distinguishing **your wife** from other people called Mary, so it's a **non-restrictive clause**, which requires commas (or pause in speech).

@SteveES also answered in a different comment:

> In other words, there isn't a difference in meaning, but 1 is grammatically incorrect and 2 is grammatically correct.

---

Additionally, I have a rule which I use to decide whether commas (or parentheses for that matter) are needed or not:

Is the sentence still understandable if the text between commas / parentheses is removed? Of course, some details are lost if words are removed, but I concentrate on the meaning of what is left.

Example:

> 1. Mary, *who is my wife*, has gone to Singapore.
> 2. Mary has gone to Singapore.

After removing the text contained between commas, the sentence remains valid. We no longer know which Mary traveled, but the sentence is valid . Therefore, the commas are welcome.

On a different note, I think it is more usual to say:

> Mary, my wife, has gone to Singapore.

Comment: Such a clause is in fact called *parenthetical*, whether it's delineated with commas, parentheses, or dashes.

Answer (score -3):

No, it does not change the meaning. The easiest way to think of it is as a pause. When speaking, if you think there should be a pause in the sentence, that should indicate placement of a comma.

Comment: While commas do indicate a place to pause in speech, they generally also have a grammatical reason for being there. Also, telling a foreign learner "put a comma where you think there should be a pause" isn't very helpful - they don't always know where there should be a pause!!